# Group dataframe by key and count fraction satisfying condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns. I want to group by column 1 and compute the fraction of all rows where column 2 matches some condition.

In SQL I'd do something like:

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  COUNTIF(col2='foo')/COUNT(*) AS ratio
GROUP BY col1
```

What's an idiomatic way to do this with pandas DataFrames?

Comment: Kindly add sample dataframes with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this dataframe:

```
>>> df
   col1 col2
0     1  foo
1     1  bar
2     2  baz
3     1  foo
4     2  bar
5     2  baz
6     1  foo
```

The intuitive way is to use `groupby_apply`:

```
>>> df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: sum(x == 'foo') / len(x))
col1
1    0.75
2    0.00
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

If you want the same shape as your original dataframe, you can use `groupby_transform`:

```
>>> df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: sum(x == 'foo') / len(x))
0    0.75
1    0.75
2    0.00
3    0.75
4    0.00
5    0.00
6    0.75
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

[count and countif in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507750/count-and-countif-in-pandas-dataframe) provides a way to do this. I will leave this question open because I'm curious if this approach is idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

A faster way is to build a column of zeros and ones, before computing the groupby:

Using @corralien's sample data:

```py
(df.assign(col2 = np.where(df.col2 == 'foo', 1, 0))
   .groupby('col1')
   .col2
   .pipe(lambda df: df.sum()/df.size())
)

col1
1    0.75
2    0.00
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Same concept applies if you want to keep the shape of the original dataframe:

```py
temp = df.assign(col2 = np.where(df.col2 == 'foo', 1, 0))
temp = temp.groupby('col1').col2
temp.transform('sum')/ temp.transform('size')

0    0.75
1    0.75
2    0.00
3    0.75
4    0.00
5    0.00
6    0.75
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```